# CAS server - can't acces CAS address after the copy of the war file generated in /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/

Tags: ldap, cas

I am currently setting up a CAS server in a local network which will have to authenticate users belonging to ldap directories so that they can then connect to a web server.
A Windows Server 2019 Active Directory is the gateway to the WAN.

Environment:

- Windows Server 2019 with Active Directory and DHCP, routing and DNS installed which make the link between the WAN and the LAN; IP: 192.168.100.10
- LDAP Server on Centos 7 on the LAN registred on the Active Directory (no ssl certificate generated); IP: 192.168.100.50
- CAS Server on Debian 11 on the LAN (no ssl certificate generated for tomcat and cas); IP: 192.168.100.101
- All pinging between each other;

I'm following this process to install and configure the cas server:
https://www.esup-portail.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=972292097

This is my build.gradle configuration file:
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Wfe.png)

This is my cas.properties configuration file:
[cas.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTv28.png)

After the copy of the war file generated in /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/; i restart tomcat9 service.

The problem is that i can't access the cas address:
[erreur_acces_site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHEb2.png)

When i check the status of Tomcat service, i got this error:
[error_tomcat_service_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGFbU.png)

Can anyone enlighten me? I can't see what's going wrong.
Moreover, if someone has a detailed procedure, which describes the environment and the prerequisites, recent and educational to install a CAS server for Centos 7, I am strongly interested
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When I remove the CAS dependencies in build.gradle and LDAP authentication config in cas.properties, I can access the [CAS login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqJuo.png).